# Collection/Array contains method

Tags: arrays, jsf, collections, el, contains

i was wondering if there's contains method for **collections/array** in EL 2.2 
or i will have to make a custom one ?

**REQUIREMENT**: i have a string array, and i want to find if it contains a specific string.

**CASE**: i am looping on list of **input checkboxes** to render them, and i want to check the current checkbox, if it's value exists in the array of checkboxes.

**UPDATE**:

- is such method is available in EL?
- If such method is not available, then please provide your suggestion for **best performance** method for a string array contains an element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a `Collection` it's easy, just use the `Colleciton#contains()` method in EL.

```
<h:panelGroup id="p1" rendered="#{bean.panels.contains('p1')}">...</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup id="p2" rendered="#{bean.panels.contains('p2')}">...</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup id="p3" rendered="#{bean.panels.contains('p3')}">...</h:panelGroup>
```

For an `Object[]` (array), you'd need a minimum of EL 3.0 and utilize its new Lambda support.

```
<h:panelGroup id="p1" rendered="#{bean.panels.stream().anyMatch(v -> v == 'p1').get()}">...</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup id="p2" rendered="#{bean.panels.stream().anyMatch(v -> v == 'p2').get()}">...</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup id="p3" rendered="#{bean.panels.stream().anyMatch(v -> v == 'p3').get()}">...</h:panelGroup>
```

If you're not on EL 3.0 yet, you'd need to create a custom EL function. For a concrete example, see [How to create a custom EL function to invoke a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174) E.g.

```
public static boolean contains(Object[] array, Object item) {
    return Arrays.asList(array).contains(item);
}
```

which is registered as

```
<function>
    <function-name>contains</function-name>
    <function-class>com.example.Functions</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean contains(java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object)</function-signature>
</function>
```

and to be used as

```
<h:panelGroup ... rendered="#{func:contains(bean.panels, 'u1')}">
```

This is not available in JSTL. There's a [`fn:contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html), but that works on `String` values only.

Comment: Just don't use arrays if you want to do a bit more than just holding the data. Use collections then.

Comment: well, i am using it on an input attribute, but the method is not getting called: `checked="#{utils.contains(myBean.array,'myBean.someIndicator') ? 'checked' : ''}"`

Comment: Are there any EL errors? By the way, the way how you use `checked` is not entirely right. A checkbox/radiobutton is checked when the whole attribute is present, regardless of its value. You basically want to print the attribute name instead of the attribute value conditionally.

Comment: aha, got you, and no i can't see EL errors, shouldn't an exception thrown if there's an EL error ?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're using `.` instead of `:`. Since `#{utils}` doesn't exist as managed bean, nothing will happen. To call functions, you need `#{prefix:functionName()}` with `:` instead.

Comment: the above method doesn't work so fine, when the value of the input is an int.

Comment: meaning if the value is 1 instead of u1 in this case equality will fail.

Comment: i have to convert item to string before comparing to work fine, but i am afraid that this may cause a problem with large numbers.

Comment: Just use `Integer` instead or modify the method to loop over the array instead of converting `int[]` to `List<int>` (which is invalid).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `String[]`, you can first concatenate all the elements of an array into a string using [`fn:join()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_join.htm):

```
<c:set var="concat" value="${fn:join(myArray, '-')}"/>
```

And then use the [`fn:contains()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_contains.htm)` function in order to check if a value exists in that string:

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(concat, 'myString')}">Found!</c:if>
```

Comment: This simple solution helped me as I wanted to check a `${ param.stringArray }` of checkbox values.