# Use "contains" statement in rendered attribute on "h:outputlink" JSF

Tags: jsf, rendered-attribute

Simply I have an array in my back-bean included some values like '1'-'2'-'3'-'4'-'5'
In JSF I want to use rendered attribute in h:outputlink to visible or invisible a link on data-table rows based on some value from each row
for example I can have the unique id in each row like `rowvar.accountType.entity.id` which return an unique id, then I wanna check if that array which I filled it in a back bean contains this id, then rendered value should be true and the row should be visible. like this
`<h:outputLink  rendered="#{Arrays.asList(acceptedIds).contains(rowvar.accountType.entity.id) }"`

but of course it isn't correct !

Could you help me to how to handle it ?

Comment: Do you use JSF utility library OmniFaces? It has an `of:contains()` function for the very purpose.

Comment: Is it work on rendered attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using these statement

```
<c:set var="theString" value="#{MyBean.payByShetabAccount}"/>
<c:set var="theString2" value="#{rowvar.accountType.entity.name}" />

<h:outputLink styleClass="fancybox-iframe  tipsy" 
        rendered="#{fn:contains(theString, theString2) || theString == '*'}"                                        
        title="#{AccountBeanbeanMessages['property_settleToAccount_caption']}"
        value="hello.jsf">
        <h:graphicImage url="img/small-icons/list-operations/left.png" styleClass="standardTable_Icon"></h:graphicImage>
        </h:outputLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it won't work this way.

One option is to refactor your code so it uses a Collection/List which provide a `contains()` method instead of using an array. This way it makes the whole story a lot easier.

Another solution would be to implement a method on your bean which accepts an array as parameter and returns a Collection instance of the array values.

You can also implement a custom EL function. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8577011/1880810) to get an idea how to do that.

Comment: Actually I tried custom EL same as that post, but it didn't work. I don't know were is the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method that takes in an array and id and returns a boolean. Then the EL expression could look something like "#{existsInArray(array, id)}"

Comment: I tried it also, I cant pass argument from JSF to mybacjbean, I means I could not pass 'rowvar.accountType.entity.id'

Comment: Are you using older JSF version? From JSF 2+ that should be possible. We need to see your code, otherwise we can go on guessing forever.