# Compare values of list in <c:if>

Tags: jsp, arraylist, jstl

I need to loop over a particular list of rows pertaining to a database column, which is of type `Integer`. This column in the database is the foreign key to the parent column ID in the same table.

I have to match the both these values and print in the JSP if there is a match.

I've gone through this link [Evaluate list.contains string in JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490139/evaluate-list-contains-string-in-jstl) and have been trying over to get it working. I don't know where exactly I've gone wrong.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<c:forEach var="List" items="${Section.LangList}">
    <c:if test="${List['Lang'] == List['Id']}">
        ...
    </c:if> 
</c:forEach>
```

This is one of the things that I've used to compare the values. I've tried the `contains` and the `<c:set>` too. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: *Is there something that I'm missing*: to include the code of the class of the objects contained in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start property names with lowercase. The `${Section.LangList}` won't work, it has to be `${Sections.langList}`.

```
<c:forEach var="List" items="${Section.langList}">
    <c:if test="${List['Lang'] == List['Id']}">
        ...
    </c:if> 
</c:forEach>
```

If that still doesn't work, another possible cause is that the data type of the both sides is different, even though they contain the same value. E.g. `String` value of `"42"` versus `Integer` value of `42`. You need to make sure that the data types are the same.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your naming convention is terrible. Each item of a `List<Language>` surely isn't another `List`, but likely the `Language` class. Also, using the brace notation to access a property with a fixed name is unnecessary. Just use the `${bean.property}` notation. The following will make your code more conform naming conventions and more self-documenting:

```
<c:forEach var="language" items="${section.languages}">
    <c:if test="${language.lang == language.id}">
        ...
    </c:if> 
</c:forEach>
```

I only still wonder how `${language.lang}` makes sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${Section.LangList}">                   
    <c:if test="${item.lang eq item.id}">
        .....
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

if it wont work show us you class that is on iterated list