# Option Group capability for Spring Form taglib

Tags: java, spring, select, spring-mvc, taglib

In HTML we can write

```
<select name="..." value"...">
 <optgroup label="Category 1">
  <option ... />
  <option ... />
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Category 2">
  <option ... />
  <option ... />
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

In Spring `<form>` tags, how can we write thing like  to group items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently  spring mvc is not offering such functionality through its tags. This can be achieved through a nice logic given [here](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/option-group-capability-for-spring-mvc-form-taglib/).

Comment: The link is now dead, would have been better to post the content.

Comment: http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/option-group-capability-for-spring-mvc-form-taglib/

Comment: This link is also dead :(

Answer (score 2):

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3742 is still pending to be resolved. 
suggestion instead of using form:options use jstl and el to build list.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

Note the collection is `Map<String, List<KeyValueBean>>`.

It stores e.g. `Group 1 -> 
             { ("Option 1.1 Label","OPTION_1_1_VAL"), ("Option 1.2 Label","OPTION_1_2_VAL"), ..}`

```
@ModelAttribute("careerOptions")
Map<String, List<KeyValueBean>> getCareerOptions() {        
    HashMap<String, List<KeyValueBean>> result = new HashMap<String, List<KeyValueBean>>();
    result.put("Grp1", new ArrayList<KeyValueBean>());
    result.get("Grp1").add(new KeyValueBean("Option 1.1", "OPT_1_1"));
    result.get("Grp1").add(new KeyValueBean("Option 1.2", "OPT_1_2"));
    result.put("Grp2", new ArrayList<KeyValueBean>());
    result.get("Grp2").add(new KeyValueBean("Option 2.1", "OPT_2_1"));

    return result;
}
```

**JSP**

```
<form:select path="careerSelected" id="careerElement">
    <form:option label="" value="" />
    <c:forEach var="optionGroup" items="${careerOptions}">
       <optgroup label="${optionGroup.key}">
       <c:forEach var="option" items="${optionGroup.value}">
          <form:option label="${option.key}" value="${option.value}" />                             
       </c:forEach>                                                          
       </optgroup>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

**KeyValueBean** (I created my own, but Java's built-in one is [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V>`](http://%20%20Controller%20(or%20any%20Base%20Controller)) -- you can use that one, it's just the code is a bit uglier)

```
public class KeyValueBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String key;
    private String value;

    public KeyValueBean(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

**One other case: Sometimes the Select items are *MIXED* (Flat mixed with OptGroup)**

```
A
B
C (subgroup)
  - C.1
  - C.2
```

In this case, the Collection can be `Map<String,Object>` where every entry will be keyed to an **Object** : **either** (1) a String or (2) a HashMap, which we will discover from the JSP.

**Controller for a MIXED Data Structure**

```
@ModelAttribute("careerOptionsMixed")
Map<String, Object> getCareerOptionsMixed() {

    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

    result.put("Flat Option 1", "OPT_1_FLAT");
    result.put("Group Option 2", myHashMap); // Fill out your HashMap for Group (Key->Value) and add it here
    result.put("Flat Option 3", "OPT_3_FLAT");

    return result;
}
```

**JSP for the MIXED Data Structure (trick required to determine Collection or not, done via iterating and setting a var)**
In the JSP we'll need to identify whether we're getting a Collection or a String. The only way to do this is via iteration and setting a variable.

```
<form:select path="career" id="careerField">
   <form:option label="" value="" />
   <c:forEach var="optionOrOptionGroup" items="${careerOptionsMixed}">
      <%--  Must use iteration to find out if this is a Collection or not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1490171/1005607 --%>
      <c:set var="collection" value="false" />
      <c:forEach var="potentialOptionGroup" items="${optionOrOptionGroup.value}" varStatus="potentialOptionGroupStatus">
         <c:if test="${potentialOptionGroupStatus.index > 0}">
            <c:set var="collection" value="true" />
         </c:if>
      </c:forEach>
      <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${collection eq true}">
            <%--  Now we know this is a LinkedHashMap --%>
            <optgroup label="${optionOrOptionGroup.key}">
               <c:forEach var="optionGroup" items="${optionOrOptionGroup.value}">
                  <form:option label="${optionGroup.key}" value="${optionGroup.value}" />
               </c:forEach>
            </optgroup>
         </c:when>
         <c:otherwise>
            <%--  Now we know this is a flat String --%>
            <form:option label="${optionOrOptionGroup.key}" value="${optionOrOptionGroup.value}" />
         </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
   </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```