# JSTL tag for comparing

Tags: jstl

Is there a JSTL tag to compare to know if a String is an Element or Member in an Array?

**Example:** 
**String to find:** Part I 
**String Array:** [Part II, Part III, Part IV]

I want to know if **Part I** is a Member of the **Array**

I tried `<fn:contains>` but it seems **Part I** is contained in **Part II** String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function available in JSTL for this.
But you can refer to below link.Hope it will help

[JSTL Sets and Lists - checking if item exists in a Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076679/jstl-sets-and-lists-checking-if-item-exists-in-a-set)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

The `fn:contains` is JSTL function which checks, whether one string is present in other string. Your string array is probably some collection, which `toString()`'s method return something like `["Part II", "Part III", "Part IV"]` and therefore the **Part I** has been found in **Part II**. This may not work for arrays - they have different string representation - something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@123456`.

You can however create your own JSTL function which will do the check.